# Entity.Contains(AttributeName) works for all annotation fields but not working for notetext

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2016

In following code snippet I am retrieving notes related to an order. It works fine only if `notetext` does contain data. Now, while debugging I found that, in other case it throws the exception that  `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I think following snippet looks good, but not sure what is missing, any idea to sort out the problem?

```
private void fetchDocument(IOrganizationService service, Guid vOrderId) 
{
    EntityCollection results = null;
    string tempNote = string.Empty;
    string tempFileName = string.Empty;

    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet("subject", "filename", "documentbody", "mimetype","notetext");
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression {
            EntityName = "annotation" ,
            ColumnSet = cols,
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions = {
                new ConditionExpression("objectid",ConditionOperator.Equal,vOrderId)
            }
            }
            };
    results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
    Entity defaultRecord = results.Entities.ElementAtOrDefault(0);

    if(defaultRecord.Contains("notetext"))
    {
        tempNote = defaultRecord.GetAttributeValue<string>("notetext");
    }

    if (defaultRecord.Contains("filename"))
    {
        tempFileName = defaultRecord.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");
    }       
}
```

Comment: What line is your Null Reference error, or what object is null?

Comment: It throws excpetion here "if(defaultRecord.Contains("notetext"))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is actually at this line:

```
Entity defaultRecord = results.Entities.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
```

There are no results found, meaning

> there is no Annotation that exists with an objectid of "vOrderId", or the user that is performing the query, doesn't have rights to read that record.

Regardless, you should just check for `defaultRecord` being null or not, and exiting if it is.

This check of null is a common occurrence, which is why I've written this ExtensionMethod:

```
public Entity GetFirstOrDefault(this IOrganizationService service, QueryBase qb) {
    return service.RetrieveMultiple(qb)?.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This would simplify your code to this:

```
private void fetchDocument(IOrganizationService service, Guid vOrderId) 
{
    EntityCollection results = null;
    string tempNote = string.Empty;
    string tempFileName = string.Empty;

    ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet("subject", "filename", "documentbody", "mimetype","notetext");
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression {
            EntityName = "annotation" ,
            ColumnSet = cols,
            Criteria = new FilterExpression
            {
                Conditions = {
                new ConditionExpression("objectid",ConditionOperator.Equal,vOrderId)
            }
            }
            };

    var defaultRecord = service.GetFirstOrDefault(query);
    if(defaultRecord != null)
    {
        if(defaultRecord.Contains("notetext"))
        {
             tempNote = defaultRecord.GetAttributeValue<string>("notetext");
        }

        if (defaultRecord.Contains("filename"))
        {
            tempFileName = defaultRecord.GetAttributeValue<string>("filename");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't guarded `defaultrecord` against null.

```
results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
if (results.Entities == null || !results.Entities.Any()) return;
Entity defaultRecord = results.Entities.ElementAt(0);
```

Extending the answer to backup `result.Entities == null` check.

Retrieve multiple `EntityCollection` is not foolproof.

`EntityCollection` property:

Decomplied SDK retrieve multiple core:

```
  protected internal virtual EntityCollection RetrieveMultipleCore(QueryBase query)
    {
      bool? retry = new bool?();
      do
      {
        bool forceClose = false;
        try
        {
          using (new OrganizationServiceContextInitializer(this))
            return this.ServiceChannel.Channel.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        }
        catch (MessageSecurityException ex)
        {
          ..
        }
        finally
        {
          this.CloseChannel(forceClose);
        }
      }
      while (retry.HasValue && retry.Value);
      return (EntityCollection) null;
    }
```

Decomplied SDK Cached Organization Serivce Context Retrieve multiple:

```
public override EntityCollection RetrieveMultiple(QueryBase query)
{
   RetrieveMultipleRequest retrieveMultipleRequest = new      RetrieveMultipleRequest();
   retrieveMultipleRequest.Query = query;
   RetrieveMultipleResponse multipleResponse = this.Execute<RetrieveMultipleResponse>((OrganizationRequest) retrieveMultipleRequest);
   if (multipleResponse == null)
     return (EntityCollection) null;
   else
     return multipleResponse.EntityCollection;
}


public EntityCollection EntityCollection
{
   get
   {
     if (this.Results.Contains("EntityCollection"))
        return (EntityCollection) this.Results["EntityCollection"];
     else
        return (EntityCollection) null;
   }
}
```

Comment: `Results.Entities` will never be `null`.  No reason to check for it.  Also adding an `Any` check is just an extra step when `defaultRecord` is not null.  Better off just retrieving the `defaultRecord` with the `ElementAtOrDefault` and checking for `defaultRecord` being null.  Finally IMHO an "if" statement with a "!" that "not's" a whole statement is less readable than a "!="

Comment: @Daryl, any documentation to support your statement `Result.Entities will never be null` ? I don't see anything mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrievemultipleresponse.aspx.  I would rather be safe with SDK/APIs I dont own and perform an extra check. `.Any ()` would only matter when lazy loading data as it would fetch data and iterate through the elements and return a bool if an element is found. It is the same as checking if elementordefault is null. As far as less readable that `!Any ()` is more readable than `All ()`.

Comment: When you look at the decomplied source code for the SDK you can see that it sets it.  Also, the `Entities` property is readonly, meaning they they have to instantiate the property in the constructor, since they don't expose an `Add` Method, or a method to instantiate it otherwise.

Comment: I was not suggesting the user of the `All`.  I was attempting to suggest that this code: `var defaultRecord = results.Entities.ElementAtOrDefault(0); if(defaultRecord == null){return;} eliminates an extra Iteration (albeit a single value iteration.  We're talking micro-optimization) of the collection if the collection has a value.  But if you feel like you'd rather check that the EntityCollection Entities property is not null, then you'd have to create a nested if, which would be less readable.

Comment: @Daryl, I have updated the answer with decompiled code, entity collection  is not foolproof. I will stand by the `Result.Entities` null check, doesn't hurt, no performance degradation. And also the `Any()` check, very readable --> `if doesn't have any` just return. I rest my case.

Comment: Touché,  Although I don't know what it would mean if it was null, besides an exception getting thrown. +1 for the better safe than sorry I guess.